# How can I find which command is bound to a given keyboard shortcut in gnome?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, d-bus, dconf

For example:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/screensaver ['<Super>l']
```

Here, <kbd>Super+L</kbd> is bound to:

```
xdg-screensaver lock
```

or,

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

I want to find out which command is run when i press a keybinding used with my window manager.

To be specific I want to know which commands are invoked by my window manager (I am using Zorin OS 16 which use Gnome Shell) for the a given keybindings.

For example, what happen when I invoke the keys for the following

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/maximize 
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/unmaximize 
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-maximized
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/minimize
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-fullscreen
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-tiled-left
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/toggle-tiled-right
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/show-desktop
```

I am fine with both CLI or dbus.

To be more specific, neither `xdotool` nor `wmctrl` is working for me. More details in https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/398

So, i need the specific commands which i want to use in a script.

Answer (score 1):

The command is `gsettings`. You can grep its output to narrow it. Then you can change the keybindings via the `Settings` GUI or the `dconf editor`. Or `gsettings` itself.

```bash
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -E 'keybindings' | grep 'Alt'

org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings activate-window-menu ['<Alt>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move ['<Alt>F7']
...
```